# Unable to set current Java version to earlier version

Tags: java, version

I have both Java 8 and 7 installed. I set the JAVA_HOME variable to the path to the java 7 jdk bin folder, and it is included in PATH. I double checked everything.

However, when I type Java -version, I get Java 8.

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: I think your java 8 bin folder is still in the PATH, and is evaluated before the java 7 bin folder :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `JAVA_HOME\bin` **to the beginning** of your path. If you´re on windows:

```
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

or

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;%PATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

Your OS will pick the java which appear first in the system environment variable called PATH. So set the Java7 home first in the path variable like this

set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

This is applicable for the terminal you have opened.

If you want to set this permanently follow the instructions

1. Right-click the My Computer icon on.
2. your desktop and select Properties.
3. Click the Advanced tab. Click the.
4. Environment Variables button. ...
5. Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
6. Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.
7. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I moved JAVA_HOME variable earlier in the PATH and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

When typing a command on your shell (both windows and linux), the executable is searched in folders specified in your `PATH` **from left to right**, i.e. if `PATH=folder1;folder2;folder3`, your shell will search for the command in the folder1, then in folder2, and finally in folder3.

I suppose your `PATH` looks like `PATH=jdk8_bin_folder;windows_stuff;jdk7_bin_folder;other_stuff`. So, when typing `java`, your shell will find the jdk8 before the jdk7.

A common solution is (as already says) to use the `JAVA_HOME` variable to store the jdk folder, and use it in your `PATH` :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things

1. Remove `Java.exe`, `javaw.exe` and `javac.exe` from `system32`folder
2. if `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` exists in path of the system environment variable then remove. when installing new version of java, installer set it automatically

Now set `JAVA_HOME` and set path(%JAVA_HOME%\bin)